# logstash http input with multiple basic auth users

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I want to setup a logstash pipeline with multiple users/passwords and use the different usernames to direct output to different elasticsearch indexes where each username has read/write access to the specific index so same credential can be used over Kibana as well. Something like -

```
input {
  http {
    host => "0.0.0.0"
    port => 5000
    user => "user1","user2"
    password => "password1","password2"
  }
}

output {
    if[user] == "user1" {
        elasticsearch {
            id => "elastic1"
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "index1"
            user => "user1"
            password => "password1"
        }
    }
    else if[user] == "user2" {
        elasticsearch {
            id => "elastic2"
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
            index => "index2"
            user => "user2"
            password => "password2"
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logstash supports basic auth, but each instance of HTTP plugin only takes in a single username-password. It doesn't support passing list of usernames / passwords:

```
http {

   port => 3332
   user => myuser
   password => "$tr0ngP4ssWD!"
   ssl => on
   keystore => "/tmp/mykeystore.jks"
   keystore_password => "keystore_pass"
}
```

Read the official documentation for HTTP plugin:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http.html#plugins-inputs-http-user

Comment: the `user` field is missing quotes on the value, i.e `user => "myuser"`